# Is there any other option of calling a number in android with out using native call?

Tags: android

I want to call a number from android with out using native call.Is that possible?
like
         startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+constant.confitacth2)));

Comment: what you mean by 'native call' ?

Comment: using   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+constant.confitacth2)));

Answer (score 0):

You can use an appropriate Intent to launch the Dialer. I believe the code you have written should work. Does it not?

Comment: its working.. but what i want is..like smsmanaager for sending sms without using intent ,is there any other process to launch a call..